# Taking matrix derivative $\| \left| \mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}\right|-\mathbf{1}_{n \times K} \| ^2_F$ with respect to W

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I am trying to take the matrix derivative of the following function with respect to $\bf W$:

\begin{equation}
\| \left| \mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}\right|-\mathbf{1}_{n \times K} \| ^2_F \\
\end{equation}

Where $\mathbf{X}$ is $n \times d$, $\mathbf{W}$ is $d \times K$ and $\mathbf{1}_{n \times K}$ is a marix with all elements one. $\| \cdot \|_F$ is the Frobenius norm and $\left| \mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}\right|$ is the element wise absolute value of $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}$.

Any helps is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For typing convenience, define the matrices
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= XW \\
 J &= 1_{n\times K} \qquad&({\rm all\,ones\,matrix}) \\
 S &= {\rm sign}(Y) \\
 A &= S\odot Y \qquad&({\rm absolute\,value\,of\,}Y) \\
 B &= A-J \\
 Y &= S\odot A \qquad&({\rm sign\,property}) \\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the elementwise/Hadamard product and the sign function is applied element-wise. Use these new variables to rewrite the function, then calculate its gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \|B\|_F^2 \\&= B:B \\
d\phi &= 2B:dB \\
 &= 2(A-J):dA \\
 &= 2(A-J):S\odot dY \\
 &= 2S\odot(A-J):dY \\
 &= 2(Y-S):dY \\
 &= 2(Y-S):X\,dW \\
 &= 2X^T(Y-S):dW \\
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial W} &= 2X^T(Y-S) \\
}$$
where a colon denotes the trace/Frobenius product, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B
 = {\rm Tr}(A^TB)
 = {\rm Tr}(AB^T)
 = B:A
}$$
The cyclic property of the trace allows such products to be rearranged in various ways
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= B^TA:C \\
     &= AC^T:B \\
}$$
Finally, when $(A,B,C)$ are all the same size, their Hadamard and Frobenius products commute with each other
$$\eqalign{
A:B\odot C &= A\odot B:C \\\\
}$$
**NB:** When an element of $\,Y$ equals zero, the gradient is undefined. This behavior is similar to the derivative of $\,|x|\,$ in the scalar case.

Comment: I just checked the derivative using TensorFlow and this is correct!
Thank you so much!
Could you please introduce me some references on this topic?

Comment: I would recommend _Matrix Differential Calculus_ by Magnus and Neudecker.

Comment: The answer from greg is great. However, in the last part of the explanation, the correct notation for a colon is as follows: $$\eqalign{
A:B = {\rm Tr}(A^TB) = {\rm Tr}(B^TA) = B:A
}$$